# Check if list values in dictionary are not empty

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I use the following *dictionary*:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> dictionary
```

How can I simply check whether one of values -> `List` of type string is *not empty*?

Comment: `dictionary[yourDateTime].Any()` ?

Comment: Do you want to know if a specific one is not empty, if none are empty or if all are empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using *Linq*:

```
 Dictionary<DateTime,List<string>> dictionary = ...

 bool hasNotEmptyValues = dictionary
   .Any(pair => pair.Value != null && pair.Value.Any());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dictionary.Values.Any(list => list.Any())
```

Then there's also the question how you see the `list == null` case.

If you want to treat it as an empty list, then:

```
dictionary.Values.Any(list => list?.Any() ?? false)
```

if not:

```
dictionary.Values.Any(list => list?.Any() ?? true)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq as follows.

```
var HasNonemptyList = dictionary.Values.Any(iList => iList.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: Almost identical to my answer, although `Any()` is more explicit than `Count() > 0`. If it was for squeezing out that last bit of performance, you could use the native `List.Count` property.